# s3fs local filecache of versioned flies

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-s3fs, fsspec

I want to use [s3fs](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/) based on [fsspec](https://pypi.org/project/fsspec/) to access files on S3. Mainly because of 2 neat features:

1. [local caching of files](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#caching-files-locally) to disk with checking if files change, i.e. a file gets redownloaded if the local and remote file differ
2. [file version id support](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#bucket-version-awareness) for versioned S3 buckets, i.e. the ability to open different versions of the same remote file based on their version id

I don't need this for high frequency use and the files don't change often. It is mainly for using unit/integration test data stored on S3, which changes only if tests and related test data get updated (versions!).

I got both of the above working separately just fine, but it seems I can't get the combination of the two working. That is, I want to be able to cache different versions of the same file locally. It seems that as soon as you use a filecache, the version id disambiguation is lost.

```py
fs = fsspec.filesystem("filecache", target_protocol='s3', cache_storage='/tmp/aws', check_files=True, version_aware=True)
with fs.open("s3://my_bucket/my_file.txt", "r", version_id=version_id) as f:
    text = f.read()
```

No matter what `version_id` is, I always get the most recent file from S3, which is also the one that gets cached locally.

What I expect is that I always get the correct file version and the local cache either keeps separate files for each version (preferred) or just updates the local file whenever I request a version different from the cached one.

Is there a way I can achieve this with the current state of the libraries or is this currently not possible?  I am using `s3fs==fsspec==2022.3.0`.

Answer (score 2):

After [checking with the developers](https://github.com/fsspec/s3fs/issues/617) this combination seems not to be possible with the current state of the libraries, since the hash of the target file is based on the filepath alone, disregarding any other `kwargs` such as `version_id`.